# "schema" for facebook realtime updates.?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

Is anyone aware of a schema for the kinds of strings facebook can send as realtime updates.?

Right now, we are listening to add activities on a page 'feed', but without knowing the different kinds of updates possible, its kind of shooting in the dark as to how what kinds of updates can come through.

Any help of reference appreciated.

Comment: Examples in the docs not enough for you?

Comment: Well.. the docs contain a couple of examples but definitely do not cover all the use cases .  In the past , I have been surprised a few times by a new node appearing for use cases that I did not anticipate at all .. I wish there was a schema to guide us in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by Schema? 
[image: Facebook Fields]

These are all the things you can listen for a user. For more information on this field you can have a look at the [Facebook Query Language](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)
If you want more information on how to parse this you can have a look at this [blog post](http://blog.shivamdaryanani.com/blog/2013/11/03/facebook-realtime-updates/).